# 64bit Enums? C#

Tags: c#, .net, enums, 64-bit

Is it possible to get an enum to hold 64bit values? I wrote the code below and got this compile error message.

```
enum EnumTest { a = 0x100000000 };
```

> error CS0266: Cannot implicitly convert type 'long' to 'int'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Yes, you need to "derive" it from long.

```
public enum MyEnum : long
{
}
```

Comment: Thanks!! For anyone tripping over this: If you use flags, you will need to use 1l << 40 instead of 1 << 40 if you use that notation.